# Recoil state only changing after reloading the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, recoiljs

I am using recoil for state management, for a very basic todo app for practice, but my todolist.tsx is not showing the updated username and I need to refresh everytime to see the updated username and todos change as soon as the username changes. I can't figure out the issue.

This is my authState

```
import { atom } from 'recoil';

export const authState = atom({
    key: 'authState',
    default: { token: null, username: null },
});
```

and this is the iniital State

```
function InitState() {
  const setAuth = useSetRecoilState(authState);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const init = async () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/auth/me', {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      console.log(data.username);
      if (data.username) {
        setAuth({ token: data.token, username: data.username });
        navigate("/todos");
      } else {
        navigate("/login");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      navigate("/login");
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    init();
  }, [])
```

and inside my todolist.tsx , I am using authStata like this :

```
  const authStateValue = useRecoilValue(authState);
```

and the username is not updating until I refresh and reload the page, todos fetched are the updated ones but the username is not updating until page is reloaded

```
 return (
        <div>
            <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                <h2>Welcome {authStateValue.username}</h2>
                <div style={{ marginTop: 25, marginLeft: 20 }}>
                    <button onClick={() => {
                        localStorage.removeItem("token");
                        navigate("/login");
                    }}>Logout</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h2>Todo List</h2>
            <input type="text" value={title} onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)} placeholder="Title" />
            <input type="text" value={description} onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)} placeholder="Description" />
            <button onClick={addTodo}>Add a new Todo</button>
            {todos.map((todo) => (
                <div key={todo._id}>
                    <h3>{todo.title}</h3>
                    <p>{todo.description}</p>
                    <button onClick={() => markDone(todo._id)} >{todo.done ? 'Done' : 'Mark as Done'}</button>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
};

export default TodoList
```

The username should also update as the todolist component re-renders , but except username everythign is fetching is being displayed fine. I can't figure out the issue, I am just starting out to use typescript with recoil